# Access gitea issues from netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, issue-tracking, gitea

Is there a way to access issues on a [Gitea server](https://gitea.io/en-us/) from [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/) (current 11.3)? I've tried to use the github connector but this doesn't work (OAuth not working, didn't dug into logs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, currently (**NetBeans 11.3**) there is not a ready solution to work with ISSUES and PR on the Gittea server using NetBeans.

The [GitHub Issues Plugin](https://github.com/junichi11/netbeans-github-issues-plugin) is the closest that we have for now. The plugin uses the [egit](https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/tree/master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core) project to connect to GitHub using the GitHub API. The egit project is compatible with GitHub API [version 3](https://developer.github.com/v3/) but was not tested with [Gittea API](https://try.gitea.io/api/swagger).

I checked the source code of both projects. There are some issues with compatibility for example:

- Egit uses `/api/v3` path ([see source](https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/blob/c749931f769858d73b9c93ea4d819e8d665335f7/org.eclipse.egit.github.core/src/org/eclipse/egit/github/core/client/IGitHubConstants.java#L195)) but Gittea uses `/api/v1` path ([see api](https://try.gitea.io/api/swagger)). It is the main reason your OAuth was not working.
- For searching issues, the plugin  uses `/search/issues` ([see source](https://github.com/junichi11/netbeans-github-issues-plugin/blob/9c286872ac74275b5743a2aeeeeedf28c25e15f4/src/main/java/com/junichi11/netbeans/modules/github/issues/egit/SearchService.java#L69)) path but gittea uses `/repos/issues/search` ([see api](https://try.gitea.io/api/swagger#/issue/issueSearchIssues))

After fixing this two I was able to connect to `try.gitea.io/api/v1` using the  GitHub Issues Plugin:

[image]

but it worked only partially. I could log in to Gittea and create issues using the modified plugin but couldn't search for issues. So more work should be done to adapt the plugin with working with `try.gitea.io/api/v1` API.

If you really need one I think you could after some work adapt the GitHub Issue Plugin to work with GitTea. Or you could ask the [author](https://github.com/junichi11/netbeans-github-issues-plugin/issues) for adaptation.